# best folder structure for your next symfony project?

Tags: symfony-2.7, symfony

I like to here which folder structure you prefer for your symfony projects? Do you use the new 3.0 version or do you prefer your own special one? I really like to hear your expert opinions.

I'm using Symfony 2.7.

Do you put the Resources folder in the app folder or in the AppBundle?
Do you have more than one bundle or do you prefer the one and only AppBundle?
DDD driven oder database driven?

Thank you in advance. :-)

Comment: There's too much questions here, that already answered in multiple places, and Symfony is quite an unopinionated framework (concerning the object model) : there's multiple answers for the same question, especially on the app/Resource and bundles questions. That said, one question can be answered in one sentence : use the 3.0 folder structure. It's better and it will be easier to upgrade to 3.0.

Answer (score 1):

There are many questions like yours in SO.

- [Symfony best practises](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/index.html)
- [Symfony - Organizing Your Business Logic](http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html)

Comment: that is not the answer I'm looking for. I'm looking for real world experience.

Comment: If you follow it, it becomes a "real world" example. I'm using it and it is a "real world" example for me!